# MySql get the count of distinct domain

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a users table like this. Users may register from different emails i.e `abc@xyz.com` and `abc@uvw.com`. I need to get the count of different domains from the email. My `users` table structure is

```
+----+------------------+------------------------+
| id | name             | email                  |
+----+------------------+------------------------+
|  3 | shamsreza        | shamsreza@abc.in       |
|  4 | Kamal            | kamalkumar@xyz.com     |
|  6 | BIBHUDATTA SAHOO | admin@uvw.com          |
|  7 | Bibhu Once Again | bibhuduttasahoo@xyz.in |
+----+------------------+------------------------+
```

I queried like this

```
select substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email)) from users
```

It's giving me output as

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email)) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| @uvw.com                                          |
| @xyz.com                                          |
| @xyz.com                                          |
| @abc.in                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

But here `xyz.com` is repeated and i need the count of distinct domains.

Comment: have you tried `select distinct substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email)) from users`

Comment: @Cashbee ok, got it, i can use like this `select COUNT(distinct substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email))) from users `

Comment: @Cashbee thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting distinct results, you can use DISTINCT.

```
select distinct substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email)) from users
```

Or in the case you want to count them:

```
select count(distinct substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email))) from users
```